# Qual é a tradução de "fireflies" em português?

Tags: etimologia, português-europeu, tradução-inglês, tradução

Em português do Brasil, "fireflies" traduz-se para "vagalume", mas qual é a expressão em português europeu? É a mesma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Português Europeu diz-se **pirilampo**. Mas não foi sempre assim, em tempos chamava-se ao insecto "cagalume".

> Sempre me fascinou um livro que tenho em casa. O título é “Prosas Portuguesas” do Padre D. Rafael Bluteau, datado de 1729.
>
> (...)
>
> São as várias licenças da Inquisição e do Ordinário, a multiplicidade de temas académicos ou não, do tempo de D. Pedro II e D. João V, muitas novidades para a época discutidas em academias como a promovida pelo Conde da Ericeira
>
> (...)
>
> D. Rafael Bluteau era um frade teatino, de origem francesa, cultíssimo e pré-iluminista.
>
> (...)
>
> Na segunda Conferencia do dito anno de 1696. Aos 19 de Fevereiro se assentaraõ as palavras seguintes.
>
> (…)
>
> Na terceira Conferencia em 26. De Fevereiro.
>   VII. **Ao insecto luzente**, a que os Latinos chamaõ Cicindela, e Noctiluca; os Gregos Lamparis, e Pirilampis; os italianos Lûciola, os Francezes Ver luisant; e os Castelhanos Luciernega, **chamaõ os Portugueses *Cagalume***; **he nome que naõ póde usarse em papeis serios, e deve dar-selhe outro** (…) Assentouse dar o nome ao insecto; **propozse Pirilampo**; achouse affectado; Fuzillete; e Vago lume se naõ admittiraõ; só pareceraõ bem os de Nouteluz; e Bicho luzente, e determinaraõ, que ambos podiaõ usarse.
>
> (...)
>
> "Oratorio Requerimento de Palavras Portuguezas, Aggravadas, Desconfiadas, Pertendentes, Presentado no Tribunal das Letras (...)", pág. 17, in D. Raphael Bluteau, Prosas Portuguezas, 1729

O artigo original foi escrito [neste blog](http://ruadealconxel.blogspot.com/2008/04/acordo-ortogrfico-2-e-o-cagalume.html). Já o li há anos, acho-o tão bem escrito e humorístico que penso merece ser citado aqui com a ligação para o original.

Comment: Em pt-BR também já ouvi "pirilampó", embora "vagalume" seja mais comum.